# Angular Compile Fails When Importing Library Function into Web Worker?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-package-format

I have a web worker that looks like this.  This used to work fine in previous Angular versions:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
import { ParseResult } from "papaparse";
import { readCSV } from '@fireflysemantics/csv';

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const result: ParseResult<any> = readCSV(data)
  postMessage(result);
});
```

If I comment out most of the worker:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
import { ParseResult } from "papaparse";
//import { readCSV } from '@fireflysemantics/csv';

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  //const response = `worker response to ${data}`;
  //postMessage(response);
});
```

Then it builds fine.  If I comment in the line:

```
import { readCSV } from '@fireflysemantics/csv';
```

Then all these errors are generated:

```
Error: ./src/app/services/csv.worker.ts (./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js?name=0!./src/app/services/csv.worker.ts)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js):
Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts:16:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

16     messageElement: Element;
                       ~~~~~~~

    at Object.addError (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/webpack-diagnostics.js:24:33)
    at /home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/diagnostics.js:19:39
    at AngularWebpackPlugin.updateJitProgram (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js:379:9)
    at /home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js:157:24
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:630:30)
    at /home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:667:29
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compiler.compile (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:28)
    at Compiler.runAsChild (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:328:8)
    at Object.pitch (/home/ole/FireflySemantics/Repository/fireflysemantics/700-CSV/new-csv/csv2/node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js:81:18)
 @ ./src/app/services/csv.service.ts 1:0-148
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts:16:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

16     messageElement: Element;
                       ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts:39:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

39     describe(hostElement: Element, message: string, role?: string): void;
m                             ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts:43:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

43     describe(hostElement: Element, message: HTMLElement): void;
                             ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts:43:45 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

43     describe(hostElement: Element, message: HTMLElement): void;
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts:45:36 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

45     removeDescription(hostElement: Element, message: string, role?: string): void;
                                      ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts:47:36 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

47     removeDescription(hostElement: Element, message: HTMLElement): void;
                                      ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts:47:54 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

47     removeDescription(hostElement: Element, message: HTMLElement): void;
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/fake-event-detection.d.ts:11:65 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TouchEvent'.

11 export declare function isFakeTouchstartFromScreenReader(event: TouchEvent): boolean;
                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/fake-event-detection.d.ts:9:64 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseEvent'.

9 export declare function isFakeMousedownFromScreenReader(event: MouseEvent): boolean;
                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:113:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

113     monitor(element: HTMLElement, checkChildren?: boolean): Observable<FocusOrigin>;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:121:33 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

121     monitor(element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, checkChildren?: boolean): Observable<FocusOrigin>;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:126:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

126     stopMonitoring(element: HTMLElement): void;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:131:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

131     stopMonitoring(element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>): void;
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:138:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

138     focusVia(element: HTMLElement, origin: FocusOrigin, options?: FocusOptions): void;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:145:34 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

145     focusVia(element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, origin: FocusOrigin, options?: FocusOptions): void;
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:182:20 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FocusEvent'.

182     _onBlur(event: FocusEvent, element: HTMLElement): void;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:182:41 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

182     _onBlur(event: FocusEvent, element: HTMLElement): void;
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.ts:210:41 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

210     constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor);
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-monitor/focus-monitor.d.tsm:97:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

97     protected _document?: Document;
                             ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/configurable-focus-trap-factory.d.ts:29:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

29     create(element: HTMLElement, config?: ConfigurableFocusTrapConfig): ConfigurableFocusTrap;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/configurable-focus-trap-factory.d.ts:34:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

34     create(element: HTMLElement, deferCaptureElements: boolean): ConfigurableFocusTrap;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/configurable-focus-trap.d.ts:26:100 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

26     constructor(_element: HTMLElement, _checker: InteractivityChecker, _ngZone: NgZone, _document: Document, _focusTrapManager: FocusTrapManager, _inertStrategy: FocusTrapInertStrategy, config: ConfigurableFocusTrapConfig);
                                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~
m

Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/configurable-focus-trap.d.ts:26:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

26     constructor(_element: HTMLElement, _checker: InteractivityChecker, _ngZone: NgZone, _document: Document, _focusTrapManager: FocusTrapManager, _inertStrategy: FocusTrapInertStrategy, config: ConfigurableFocusTrapConfig);
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:129:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

129     create(element: HTMLElement, deferCaptureElements?: boolean): FocusTrap;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:151:41 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

151     constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, _focusTrapFactory: FocusTrapFactory, _document: any);
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:23:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

23     readonly _element: HTMLElement;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:26:25 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

26     readonly _document: Document;
                           ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:36:100 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

36     constructor(_element: HTMLElement, _checker: InteractivityChecker, _ngZone: NgZone, _document: Document, deferAnchors?: boolean);
                                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:36:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

36     constructor(_element: HTMLElement, _checker: InteractivityChecker, _ngZone: NgZone, _document: Document, deferAnchors?: boolean);
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/interactivity-checker/interactivity-checker.d.ts:32:25 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

32     isDisabled(element: HTMLElement): boolean;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/interactivity-checker/interactivity-checker.d.ts:41:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

41     isVisible(element: HTMLElement): boolean;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/interactivity-checker/interactivity-checker.d.ts:49:25 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

49     isTabbable(element: HTMLElement): boolean;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/interactivity-checker/interactivity-checker.d.ts:57:26 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

57     isFocusable(element: HTMLElement, config?: IsFocusableConfig): boolean;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/key-manager/list-key-manager.d.ts:101:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'KeyboardEvent'.

101     onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent): void;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/live-announcer/live-announcer-tokens.d.ts:11:67 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

11 export declare const LIVE_ANNOUNCER_ELEMENT_TOKEN: InjectionToken<HTMLElement | null>;
                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/dir-document-token.d.ts:24:51 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

24 export declare const DIR_DOCUMENT: InjectionToken<Document>;
                                                     ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/dir-document-token.d.ts:26:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

26 export declare function DIR_DOCUMENT_FACTORY(): Document;
                                                   ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:17:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationCallback'.

17     create(callback: MutationCallback): MutationObserver | null;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:17:41 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationObserver'.

17     create(callback: MutationCallback): MutationObserver | null;
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:31:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

31     observe(element: Element): Observable<MutationRecord[]>;
                        ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:31:43 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationRecord'.

31     observe(element: Element): Observable<MutationRecord[]>;
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:36:33 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

36     observe(element: ElementRef<Element>): Observable<MutationRecord[]>;
                                   ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:36:55 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationRecord'.

36     observe(element: ElementRef<Element>): Observable<MutationRecord[]>;
                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:60:25 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationRecord'.

60     event: EventEmitter<MutationRecord[]>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:73:76 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

73     constructor(_contentObserver: ContentObserver, _elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, _ngZone: NgZone);
                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/platform/features/shadow-dom.d.ts:11:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

11 export declare function _getShadowRoot(element: HTMLElement): ShadowRoot | null;
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/platform/features/shadow-dom.d.ts:11:63 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ShadowRoot'.

11 export declare function _getShadowRoot(element: HTMLElement): ShadowRoot | null;
                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2679:30 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

2679     abstract getProperty(el: Element, name: string): any;
                                  ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2684:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

2684     abstract remove(el: any): Node;
                                   ~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2685:54 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.

2685     abstract createElement(tagName: any, doc?: any): HTMLElement;
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2686:36 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

2686     abstract createHtmlDocument(): HTMLDocument;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~


9mError: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2687:36 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

2687     abstract getDefaultDocument(): Document;
                                        ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2692:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

2692     abstract getGlobalEventTarget(doc: Document, target: string): any;
                                            ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2693:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'History'.

2693     abstract getHistory(): History;
                                ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2695:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

2695     abstract getBaseHref(doc: Document): string | null;
                                   ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:449:47 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

449 export declare const DOCUMENT: InjectionToken<Document>;
                                                  ~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:10413:62 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

10413 export declare function ɵgetDebugNode__POST_R3__(nativeNode: Element): DebugElement__POST_R3__;
                                                                   ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:10415:62 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

10415 export declare function ɵgetDebugNode__POST_R3__(nativeNode: Node): DebugNode__POST_R3__;
                                                                   ~~~~
```

The `readCsv()` Method is exported from an Angular Package Format library an looks like this:

```
export function readCSV(csv: string, config = CSV_DEFAULT_CONFIG): ParseResult<any> {
  return parse(csv.trim(), config);
}
```

This used to work fine until upgrading the Angular version just now.

Any ideas?  I can't stackblitz this because web workers don't run on Stackblitz ...

## Environment

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.0.7
Node: 12.6.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.0.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.7
@angular/cdk                    11.2.3
@angular/cli                    11.0.7
@angular/material               11.2.3
@schematics/angular             11.0.7
@schematics/update              0.1100.7
ng-packagr                      11.2.4
rxjs                            6.6.6
typescript                      4.0.7
```

Comment: Also created an Angular Issue for this here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41357

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened because I added components to the library that exports the `readCSV` function.  The Angular compilation does not allow compiling of dependencies that have DOM APIs in them (Depend on Angular CDK etc.), thus the errors.

The solution will be to put the components in a separate library.

Comment: Not a practice solution in my case, but thank you

Comment: To clarify this, the reason it doesn't work is that the web worker is compiled with a different tsconfig, which doesn't include the DOM library (since workers can't access the DOM), so if the web worker, or anything imported into the web worker, imports something from the DOM library it will break. So you need to avoid importing such things into web workers.